# Get SharePoint user id from login name

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I need to retrieve `current user id` from login name.

How can that be done?
I have used the following code:

```
var userid=Function??("domain\name");
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are not looking for the current User...I imagine it would be something like this, although I have not tested this nor have I done it before.

```
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var website = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = website.ensureUser("domain\name");
    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);

    function onRequestSucceeded() {
       var userid =  currentUser.get_id();
    }

    function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
        //error handling
        alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }
```

Although it is important to note that ensure user will add the users to the given web if they don't already exist.

Comment: all correct except the `currentUser.UserID` should be `currentUser.get_id()`

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to make a request to the server when the `userid` is already loaded in browser.

**You can use**:

```
_spPageContextInfo.userId
```

available in SharePoint 2013 and Online (wave 16).

Comment: This one line code is fine but user does not need current login user id

Answer (score 1):

To get the userId of a user from the account/login name can be obtained by:

```
        function GetUserIdFromUserName(userName) {
        /// according to the environment.
        var prefix = "i:0#.w|";
        var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
        var accountName = prefix + userName;
        $.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + 
                encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Received UserId " + data.d.Id);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410544(v=office.14).aspx) for an example on how to get the current user in JavaScript.

Once you have the user, you can use `.get_id()` to get the record ID for the user.