# How can I get UserId from people picker column value?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Here an example of what I nedd to accopmlish:

```
column value = "i:0#.w|domain\user"
```

I need user id so that i am able to set username for that column.

Comment: Using what? js or C#?

Comment: @atish Using JS

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73877/get-sharepoint-user-id-from-login-name) asked on Stack Exchange and refer first answer given by @Blue Bird, which I have copied here...

> var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
> var website = clientContext.get_web();
> currentUser = website.ensureUser("domain\name");
> clientContext.load(website);
> clientContext.load(currentUser);
> clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
>
> function onRequestSucceeded() {
>       var userid =  currentUser.get_id();
> }
>
> function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
>        //error handling
>        alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
> }

Ask if you have any query..

Comment: Please mark as answer if you found this answer right..

Answer (score 0):

You can get User Id from login name by following way

```
function GetUserId(userName) {
            /// change this prefix according to the environment. 
            /// In below sample, windows authentication is considered.
            var prefix = "i:0#.w|";
            /// get the site url
            var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
            /// add prefix, this needs to be changed based on scenario
            var accountName = prefix + userName;

            /// make an ajax call to get the site user
            $.ajax({
                url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + 
                    encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    ///popup user id received from site users.
                    alert("Received UserId" + data.d.Id);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        }
```

Details is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/798407/SharePoint-REST-API-Get-User-Id-by-User-Name)

Comment: Will check it and let you know

Comment: Its showing internal server error

Comment: Can update the question with your code?